# Making a circle with '*' C++

Tags: c++

I am making a circle and the code works fine but the problem is that even though it is working the circle is not perfect, or close as it can be.

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

int main() 
{
    int radius = 6;
    int i,j;
    for (i=0; i<=2*radius; i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j<=2*radius; j++)
        {
            double distance = sqrt((double)(i-radius)*(i-radius) + (j-radius)*(j-radius));
            if (distance>radius-0.65 && distance<radius+0.2)
            {
                std::cout << "*";
            }
            else
            { 
                std::cout << "  ";
            }
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The circle looks like a lemon and has some weird spaces in different places
output:

```
          ***                                                                                                                                
      **      **                                                                                                                             
    *              *                                                                                                                         
  *                  *                                                                                                                       
  *                  *                                                                                                                       
*                      *                                                                                                                     
*                      *                                                                                                                     
*                      *                                                                                                                     
  *                  *                                                                                                                       
  *                  *                                                                                                                       
    *              *                                                                                                                         
      **      **                                                                                                                             
          ***              
//               ^ 
//               Wierd spacing
//               Oval-ish
```

Comment: I wondered how an algorithm that didn't rely on `-0.65` and `0.2` would look.  http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bfe897795553e15a

Comment: @MooingDuck That looks like the skeleton of a really nice answer.

Comment: It does not completely rely on those numbers Its just that there are less asterisks if i make the range smaller, bigger range also decreases accurecy of the points though.

Comment: @cigien: It doesn't answer his problem though. It's merely an entirely unrelated algorithm, so not in the right direction of a good answer. It would be easy, in fact, for my algorithm to have the same bug as the question.

Comment: @MooingDuck That's true. It should probably be a different Q&A, though it might be a little difficult to make it on-topic.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> ```
> std::cout << "*";
> ```
>
> ```
> std::cout << "  ";
> ```

You're printing one asterisk but two spaces. These statements need to print the same number of characters. With the right font, two asterisks `"**"` looks pretty good:

[image: Adjusted drawing]

As does asterisk-space `"* "`:

[image: Adjusted drawing]